# A reliable way to check if two variables in a cmd shell point to the same folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

It can't be checked just by comparing these variables:

```
C:\>set "d1=C:\"
C:\>set "d2=C:\Windows\.."
C:\>if %d1%==%d2% (echo true) else (echo false)
false
```

I can make up a sophisticated construct with `pushd` and `popd` and additional variables but isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: IMHO `C:` isn't an absolute path, instead it's an relative path of the current dir on drive C:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to jeb's solution, but using FOR instead of called subroutine

```
for %%A in ("%d1%") do for %%B in ("%d2%") do if "%%~fA"=="%%~fB" (echo true) else (echo false)
```

Comment: @Andriy M - The quotes you added to the IF comparison don't hurt, but they aren't necessary. The IF statement special parsing occurs before the FOR variable expansion, so spaces and special characters don't cause a problem, even if not quoted.

Answer (score 5):

You could normalize the variables with a small function.

```
set d1=C:\
set d2=C:\Windows\..
call :normalize d1
call :normalize d2
if "%d1%"=="%d2%" (echo true) else (echo false)
exit /b

:normalize
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%M in ("!%1!") do (
    endlocal
    set "%1=%%~dpM"
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Does not work. My input file path's were A and B, and result was B and B. Also on the other case when the folder does not had the trailing backslash \ the last folder was trimmed. Though, the @dbenham one line solution above seems to be working fine.

Comment: @addons_zz You are right. I fixed now the forgotten expansion of %1

Answer (score 1):

dont know if it will suite to your need but you could create a file on 1st dir anc check if it exists in second :

```
echo test > %d1%\checkthisfile.txt
if exist %d2%\checkthisfile.txt (echo true)
```

Comment: It does not look very reliable. Besides, it may be slow.