# How to check if two variables in a shell script point to the same folder?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

#### How to check if two variables in a shell script point to the same folder?

It can't be checked just by comparing these variables:

```
d1=/home/
d2=/home/user/../

if [ "$d1" == "$d2" ]
then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi

... outputs false
```

Let us assume: `d1` and `d2`, both are directories paths on the file system and are pointing to the same directory. However they are written differently as  `/home/` and `/home/user/../`. Therefore simples checking for equal strings does not work here.

---

Inspired by the question:

1. [A reliable way to check if two variables in a cmd shell point to the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789391/a-reliable-way-to-check-if-two-variables-in-a-cmd-shell-point-to-the-same-folder)

Within the answer:

```
for %%A in ("%d1%") do for %%B in ("%d2%") do if "%%~fA"=="%%~fB" (echo true) else (echo false)
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Shell script, linux. I need to do the same task on linux.

Comment: @addons_zz: Your requirement is not clear. Which two variables do you want to compare?

Comment: Let us assume: `var1` and `var2`, both are directories paths on the file system and are pointing to the same directory. However they are written differently as  `/home/` and `/home/../`. Therefore simples checking for equal strings does not work here.

Comment: @addons_zz: Refer the comments below this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/42105841/5291015, `/home/` and `/home/../` are never the same

Comment: `[ "$(readlink -f "$d1")" == "$(readlink -f "$d2")"  ]`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to got deeper one level. Now it is fixed: `/home/` and `/home/user/../`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var1="/home/ps/temp/.."
var2="/home/ps/"


if [ "$(readlink -f "$var1")" == "$(readlink -f "$var2")" ];then
    echo "they are pointing to same directory...."

else

    echo "NOOOOO they are different"

fi
```

From `man readlink` :

> -f, --canonicalize
>
> canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively; all but the last component must exist

Comment: You beat me by few seconds :-)

Comment: Also worth adding a note, `-f` in `readlink` is `GNU` specific, not `POSIX`

Comment: So, I tested it here and it works for my case `/home/` and `/home/user/../`. This answer seems also to work even if they were symlinks, it would be a bonus.

Comment: Does this work with mounted volumes (eg. `mount1` with `/destination`, and a symbolic link located on `mount2` with `destination -> /destination`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the stat command to report the inode number. Use a trailing backslash to insure any symlinks are dereferenced.

```
inode_1=`stat -f "%i" ../../d1/`
inode_2=`stat -f "%1" /path/to/d2/which/links/to/d1/`
[[ $inode_1 -eq $inode_2 ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

Comment: This will never be true. Because no 2 directories will have same inode number. (hard links to directories is not allowed.)

Comment: ^^ I take that back. For symlinks, this will not work, but for OP's case, `/home/user/..` and `/home` will have same inode number.

Comment: `$ ls -ld /Users/jj`

`drwxr-xr-x+ 51 jj  staff  1734 Feb  9 13:15 /Users/jj`

`$ ls -ld /tmp/link-to-jj`

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 jj  wheel  9 Feb  9 14:59 /tmp/link-to-jj -> /Users/jj`

`$ stat -f "%i" /Users/jj/`

`618366`

`$ stat -f "%i" /tmp/link-to-jj/`

`618366`

`$`